# datatable in bootstrap tab on revisit shows no data available

Tags: jquery, angular, datatable

I have datatable populated using ng-repeat in one tab. if i visit other tab and come back, my table is populated but shows no data available. 
On first load all the features of datatable like sorting , searching, paging. works. but on revisit nothing works. please help me.

```
<table id="example" class="books-table table table-striped"  ui-jq="dataTable" datatable="ng" ui-options="dataOpt" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Book name</th>
         <th>Author</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr dt-rows ng-repeat="book in data" emit-last-repeat-element>
         <td>{{book.from}}</td>
         <td>{{book.to}}</td>
         <td class="action-icons">
            <a href="#/books/edit/{{book._id}}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js file

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ui.utils','datatables'])
.config(config)
.run(run);
//here all the state provider code..
```

index controller is

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Books.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller(BookService,UserService,$scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.userid=null;
        vm.books = [];
        $scope.data=[];

        initController();

        function initController() {

              UserService.GetCurrent().then(function (user) {
                vm.userid = user._id;

              });
              vm.loading = true;
            BookService.GetAll()
                 .then(function (books) {
                    vm.loading = false;
                    vm.books = books;
                    $scope.data=vm.books;
                });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var table=$('#example').DataTable();
        });

    }
})();
```

Comment: You should format your JS code for readability.

Comment: It's bad to use jquery with angular

Answer (score 0):

There is already an example in datatable docs which use bootstrap tab [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html)

so you need to add

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
} );
```

Comment: There is no problem with alignment. if i add the given statements on first time load itself populating and giving message no data available.

Comment: try to use this event and reinitialise data table inside it